# What does 2>&1 mean here?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, redirect

I tried this code in bash :

```
 >$(
 >echo bonjour
 >echo bonsoir 2>&1
 >)
```

So just after that the result was : bonsoir, 
After when i did

```
>$ cat toto
```

The result was : bonjour, I just want to understand what 2>$1 did exactely here ?

Comment: It means redirect the output of stderr (file descriptor 2) to stdout (file descriptor 1).

Comment: `2>$1` should be `2>&1`, then what @ElliottFrisch says it correct.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that would be true if the command was 2>&1 , not $1.... Unless $1 has a kind of value... OP is not providing all the details i.e where file toto came from? It could be possible that $1 is set to 'toto' , sto the command 2>$1 actually means 2>toto

Comment: I assume there is at least 1 (if not many) typos at play in this question. Your question is `What does 2>&1 mean here ?` but the code says `2>$1`. What are you trying to achieve here? If you want to learn more about bash redirection, try delving into `man bash` or checkout this [link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: Sorry, i tried 2>&1 it was just a mistake

Comment: Even better, here is a the redirection section of the `bash manpage` titled [Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bash/bash.1.en.html#Redirecting_Standard_Output_and_Standard_Error), which gives a better explanation than I ever could.

Answer (score 7):

Before talking about redirections i have the feeling that you need to understand a basic thing:
Linux commands produce normal output and error output, and unix gives you the freedom to "redirect" each output to a separate "channel" , called file descriptors (fd).

Channel/fd 1 is used for std ouput and Channel/fd 2 is used for error output.

For example you can have a command to run like this :

```
$ command 1>output 2>errors #or more simple command >output 2>errors . A simple >output is a shortcut to 1>output
```

In above command nothing will be printed on your screen. Normal output will be sent to a local file called 'output' and errors will be sent to a local file called 'errors'.

Now imagine yourself with two monitors, named tty0 and tty1. 
You might distinguish output using something like

```
$ command 1>/dev/tty0 2>/dev/tty1
```

In this situation normal output of the command goes to channel 1 = tty0 and errors goes to channel 2 = tty1.

When you ommit redirections and you run a command by your shell prompt, channel 1 and channel 2 are both redirected to your one and only screen (tty0).

So by just running in your shell

```
$ command
```

is by default equivalent to

```
$ command 1>/dev/tt0 2>/dev/tt0
```

When we have a variable assignment (like your example) then the game is a bit different.
Shell creates a temp place (or a variable space if you prefer) to hold the normal output produced by the command, but the error output is not driven to the variable by default.

So for a variable assignment like this one

```
variable=$(command)
```

equals somehow to:

```
command 1>$variable 2>/dev/tt0    #this is not a valid syntax , it is just an example to demonstrate how different ouputs are handled by default.
```

Error output keeps going to tty0, your screen, unless you explicitly redirect error output to somewhere else like `2>file` (send errors to a file) or `2>&1` = sent error output to the same location that normal output goes => variable.

Consider these tests:

```
echo "hello world" >hello.txt 
#we create a simple file. Channel number is not given but is considered to be 1 by defauly, so this is equivalent to echo "..." 1>hello.txt 
ls -all
> drwx------    2 9925691 root   4096 Dec 13 01:29 .
> drwxr-xr-x 2802 root    root 253952 Dec 13 01:29 ..
> -rw-r--r--    1 9925691 root     12 Dec 13 01:29 hello.txt

a=$(ls -all hello.txt) #variable assignment ignoring the error output
echo "Lets print the contents of variable 'a' : $a"
> Lets print the contents of variable 'a' : -rw-r--r-- 1 9925691 root 12 Dec 13 01:31 hello.txt

echo "one more test"
b=$(ls -all helo.txt) #there is no file helo.txt so this will produce an error
echo "variable 'b' contains: $b"
> one more test
> variable 'b' contains:  #nothing is printed in normal output &1 so the variable is null
> ls: cannot access 'helo.txt': No such file or directory #this error is printed directly to tty0, is not stored in variable "$a" and thus can not be used later on from your scripts.

echo "another test'
c=$(ls -all helo.txt 2>&1)
echo "variable 'c' contains: $c"
> another test
> variable 'c' contains: ls: cannot access 'helo.txt': No such file or directory #Variable $c contains the error output of the command ls.
> #nothing is printed on your screen directly. is all stored in variable "$c"
```

Answer (score 1):

2>&1 is shell notation for redirecting stream 2 (stderr) to stream 2 (stdout) so that all of your normal output and your error output go to the same stream. This is useful if you want to direct them both to the same file, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In these redirect cases, you can use stdout (1) or stderr (2).  When running `2>&1`, you're redirecting stderr to stdout.  To make things easier to read:

```
stderr(2) > stdout(1)
```

When running the following code:

```
>$(
>echo bonjour
>echo bonsoir 2>&1
>)
```

Both `bonjour` and `bonsoir` should've been printed to the console because stdout is defaulted to the console and you're redirecting stderr to stdout.  Since there aren't any errors, both should go to stdout (or to the console).

Answer (score 0):

Unix shells use streams to handle input & output. The streams are referenced by number starting at 0.  Every shell provides 3 streams for you

standard input (stdin) is number 0 and is where default input stream (data coming into your script)

standard output (stdout) is number 1 which is used for normal output

standard error (stderr) is number 2 which is used for sending error messages

stdout and stderr are conventions. You don't have to use them like that (but you really should try to).

2>&1 is shell notation for redirecting stream 2 (stderr) to stream 2 (stdout) so that all of your normal output and your error output go to the same stream.  This is useful if you want to direct them both to the same file, for example.